# C# TimeOut Method

Tags: c#

I have the following code but it is not executing for the TimeOut object for inactivity

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("booting up....");

    programController.init(this);

    disableFetchSetData();
    label3.Hide();
    logoutButton.Hide();

    //Added Timer Object to log out of program
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (10 * 60 * 1000); // 10 mins
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimeOut);
    MyTimer.Start();
}
     

public void TimeOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    MessageBox.Show("The form will now close due to inactivity");
    this.Close();
}
```

Why is this? It is supposed to execute from the Load() of the Form. Since the TimeOut method is an event, it is called upon the Load of the Form.

Comment: `TimeOut` will be called on every `MyTimer` tick, which you've set to be 10 minutes. Are you waiting for the whole 10 minutes? I've tested with 3 seconds and it worked

Comment: Your biggest problem is memory leak... check if this timer is not living forever